# Cannot use pre_set_site_transient_update_themes from within a theme in multisite

Tags: multisite, filters

I built a custom update script for a theme which can be bought on my site and put it directly into the theme, so no additional plugin has to be installed. Works well on single sites, but it seems that the `pre_set_site_transient_update_themes` filter does not work on a multisite installation. I just get no update notification for the theme…

This is a simplified version of my solution:

```
function schlicht_theme_update( $transient ) {
    if ( empty( $transient->checked ) ) {
        return $transient;
    }

    $request = schlicht_fetch_data_of_latest_version();
    if ( is_wp_error( $request ) || wp_remote_retrieve_response_code( $request ) != 200 ) {
        return $transient;
    } else {
        $response = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $request );
    }

    $data     = json_decode( $response );
    if ( version_compare( $transient->checked['schlicht'], $data->new_version, '<' ) ) {
        $transient->response['schlicht'] = (array) $data;
        $transient->response['schlicht']['theme'] = 'schlicht';
    }

    return $transient;
}

add_filter( 'pre_set_site_transient_update_themes', 'schlicht_theme_update' );
```

Is there a way to use the filter from within a theme in multisite? Or do I have to create a plugin…

Comment: I have also encountered the same issue.. Did you find any solution @florian?

Comment: @Paras no, unfortunately not. Maybe something has changed there in the meantime, but I did not look at it for a longer time now…

Comment: here's what I found from some research. This works when the theme is activated on the main site of the network. The reason for that is, the sub-sites in a multi-site network doesn't have their own update mechanism. So, when this theme is activated on sub-sites, the hook probably never gets executed. The solution to this would be to install a plugin to execute the hook and modify this filter..